# How to get an alert to appear when a certain option is selected from the dropown menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, alert

I'm trying to get display an alert to the user when they select an option from the dropdown menu, so depending on what option is chosen a different alert will display. I have this so far

```js
function tagChange(dropdown) {
  for (var i, x = 0; i = dropdown.options[x]; x++) {
    if (i.value == "a") {
      alert("you've clicked a");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="tagChange(this);" name="topic">
          <option disabled selected value> -- none selected -- </option>
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
```

It shows the alert but for every option that is clicked, not just a certain one.

Comment: The answer below is right, but in terms of what you've written.. check the syntax of your for loop. You've declared but not assigned the `i` variable, and then tried to assign and iterate using the x variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use with `dropdown.value` .For loop is not necessary .

**Note ***:  Dont forget to add bracket in function open and close `function(){ }`.you are missing the `{` in function start

```js
function tagChange(dropdown) {
  if (dropdown.value == "a") {
    alert("you've clicked a");
  }

}
```

```html
<select onchange="tagChange(this);" name="topic">
      <option disabled selected value> -- none selected -- </option>
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
  </select>
```